# How do you automatically set a UUID for a row in Supabase using the Flutter SDK?

Tags: flutter, supabase, supabase-flutter

I see in the Supabase docs that there is a built-in [gen_random_uuid()](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/extensions/uuid-ossp#uuidgeneratev4) function which can be used to generate an ID automatically for each new row. For some reason this isn't working for me. When I try to create a new user I get this error:

`PostgrestException(message: null value in column "id" of relation "users" violates not-null constraint, code: 23502, details: Bad Request, hint: null)`

Here is my table schema:

[image]

And here is my ID column setup:

[image]

On the Flutter side, I am creating a new user like this:

```
Future<void> createUser() async {
    try {
      FastUser newUser = FastUser(createdAt: DateTime.now());

      await _supabase.from('users').insert(newUser.toJson());
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error creating user: $e');
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can bypass the error by disabling "Is Primary Key" in the constraints, save, and then check "Allow Nullable". But that doesn't really solve the issue because one would expect this will auto-generate the whole id column, but it just creates a null value. I'm resorting to external UUID generator library for now.

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue. I was using the [@JsonSerializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) annotation which includes all null values by default in the toJson() output.

To fix this, I needed to add `@JsonKey(includeIfNull: false)` over the "id" field:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:neurd/features/shared/utils/json/utils.dart';

part 'fast_user.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class FastUser {

  @JsonKey(includeIfNull: false) // Added this
  String? id;

  String? email;

  FastUser({
    this.id,
    this.email,
  });

  factory FastUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$FastUserFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FastUserToJson(this);
}
```